# Audio play issue on button click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working with unity and have problem with audio. Here is scenario when user click on button, Object falls on ground and destroy. When click on button sound effect of object falling is play. And destroy, Object is instantiate again then same click sound effect is play again. But when one object is falling and does not collide at this time user click again that button sound play again. I want that when one object is complete destroy than again click happen and sound is play.

Code CubeScript:

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {


    Rigidbody2D body;


    void Start () {

        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        body.isKinematic = true;
    }


}
```

Code ColliderScript:

```
public class Ground : MonoBehaviour {

    private Button bt;

    public GameObject cube;

    public AudioSource source;

    public AudioClip clip;

    void Start () {


        bt = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Button").GetComponent<Button> ();

        bt.onClick.AddListener (() => Fall ());
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
        Instantiate (cube,new Vector3(0f,4.19f,0f),Quaternion.identity);


    }


    public void Fall(){

        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().isKinematic = false;

        source.PlayOneShot(clip);


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
    Destroy (col.gameObject);
    Instantiate (cube,new Vector3(0f,4.19f,0f),Quaternion.identity);
    isFalling = false;  // here
}

private bool isFalling = false;  // here
public void Fall()
{
    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().isKinematic = false;
    if(isFalling == false){
        source.PlayOneShot(clip);
        isFalling = true;   // here
    }
}
```

Pretty much when you press, it calls Fall, if nothing is falling down, the sound happens. On Collision, the isFalling is reset. Tho I am not entirely sure about your logic.